# Update rows that exist and add rows that do not exist in R

Tags: r

I wonder how I can update this data, the idea is that I have a historical database df 1

| ID | StartDate | EndDate | Pet |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10-04-2021 | 16-04-2021 | Cat |
| 2 | 21-04-2021 |  | Horse |
| 3 | 10-04-2021 | 19-04-2021 | Dog |
| 4 | 03-04-2021 | 15-04-2021 | Dog |
| 5 | 25-04-2021 |  | Fish |
| 6 | 06-04-2021 | 16-04-2021 | Cat |
| 7 | 22-04-2021 |  | Horse |
| 8 | 11-04-2021 | 21-04-2021 | Fish |

and an update df2

| ID | StartDate | EndDate | Pet |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 21-04-2021 | 22-04-2021 | Horse |
| 5 | 25-04-2021 | 27-04-2021 | Fish |
| 9 | 25-04-2021 | 29-04-2021 | Dog |
| 10 | 27-04-2021 | 30-04-2021 | Dog |

The idea is to see from df2 which already exist in df1 and update them, and those that are not, add them completely.

| ID | StartDate | EndDate | Pet |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10-04-2021 | 16-04-2021 | Cat |
| 2 | 21-04-2021 | 22-04-2021 | Horse |
| 3 | 10-04-2021 | 19-04-2021 | Dog |
| 4 | 03-04-2021 | 15-04-2021 | Dog |
| 5 | 25-04-2021 | 27-04-2021 | Fish |
| 6 | 06-04-2021 | 16-04-2021 | Cat |
| 7 | 22-04-2021 |  | Horse |
| 8 | 11-04-2021 | 21-04-2021 | Fish |
| 9 | 25-04-2021 | 29-04-2021 | Dog |
| 10 | 27-04-2021 | 30-04-2021 | Dog |

Comment: Share your dataset. And code attempt you did. So I can know where you are doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

We could bind the datasets together, do an `arrange` and grouped by the columns `slice` the first row

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(df1, df2) %>%
   arrange(ID, StartDate, Pet, is.na(EndDate)) %>%
   group_by(ID, StartDate, Pet) %>%
   slice_head(n = 1) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 x 4
#      ID StartDate  EndDate    Pet  
#   <int> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>
# 1     1 10-04-2021 16-04-2021 Cat  
# 2     2 21-04-2021 22-04-2021 Horse
# 3     3 10-04-2021 19-04-2021 Dog  
# 4     4 03-04-2021 15-04-2021 Dog  
# 5     5 25-04-2021 27-04-2021 Fish 
# 6     6 06-04-2021 16-04-2021 Cat  
# 7     7 22-04-2021 <NA>       Horse
# 8     8 11-04-2021 21-04-2021 Fish 
# 9     9 25-04-2021 29-04-2021 Dog  
#10    10 27-04-2021 30-04-2021 Dog
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
unique(rbindlist(list(df1, df2))[order(ID, StartDate, Pet, 
        is.na(EndDate))], by = c("ID", "StartDate", "Pet"))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:8, StartDate = c("10-04-2021", "21-04-2021", 
"10-04-2021", "03-04-2021", "25-04-2021", "06-04-2021", "22-04-2021", 
"11-04-2021"), EndDate = c("16-04-2021", NA, "19-04-2021", "15-04-2021", 
NA, "16-04-2021", NA, "21-04-2021"), Pet = c("Cat", "Horse", 
"Dog", "Dog", "Fish", "Cat", "Horse", "Fish")), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))

df2 <- structure(list(ID = c(2L, 5L, 9L, 10L), StartDate = c("21-04-2021", 
"25-04-2021", "25-04-2021", "27-04-2021"), EndDate = c("22-04-2021", 
"27-04-2021", "29-04-2021", "30-04-2021"), Pet = c("Horse", "Fish", 
"Dog", "Dog")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  full_join(df2) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(na.omit))
```

Output:

```
      ID StartDate  EndDate    Pet  
   <int> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>
 1     1 10-04-2021 16-04-2021 Cat  
 2     2 21-04-2021 22-04-2021 Horse
 3     2 21-04-2021 22-04-2021 Horse
 4     3 10-04-2021 19-04-2021 Dog  
 5     4 03-04-2021 15-04-2021 Dog  
 6     5 25-04-2021 27-04-2021 Fish 
 7     5 25-04-2021 27-04-2021 Fish 
 8     6 06-04-2021 16-04-2021 Cat  
 9     8 11-04-2021 21-04-2021 Fish 
10     9 25-04-2021 29-04-2021 Dog  
11    10 27-04-2021 30-04-2021 Dog
```

data:

```
df1 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~ID,   ~StartDate,     ~EndDate,    ~Pet,
   1L, "10-04-2021", "16-04-2021",   "Cat",
   2L, "21-04-2021",           NA, "Horse",
   3L, "10-04-2021", "19-04-2021",   "Dog",
   4L, "03-04-2021", "15-04-2021",   "Dog",
   5L, "25-04-2021",           NA,  "Fish",
   6L, "06-04-2021", "16-04-2021",   "Cat",
   7L, "22-04-2021",           NA, "Horse",
   8L, "11-04-2021", "21-04-2021",  "Fish"
  )


df2 <- tibble::tribble(
    ~ID,   ~StartDate,     ~EndDate,    ~Pet,
     2L, "21-04-2021", "22-04-2021", "Horse",
     5L, "25-04-2021", "27-04-2021",  "Fish",
     9L, "25-04-2021", "29-04-2021",   "Dog",
    10L, "27-04-2021", "30-04-2021",   "Dog"
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine the two datasets, `arrange` and keep the unique rows by `ID`.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  bind_rows(df2) %>%
  arrange(ID, is.na(EndDate)) %>%
  distinct(ID, .keep_all = TRUE)

#   ID  StartDate    EndDate   Pet
#1   1 10-04-2021 16-04-2021   Cat
#2   2 21-04-2021 22-04-2021 Horse
#3   3 10-04-2021 19-04-2021   Dog
#4   4 03-04-2021 15-04-2021   Dog
#5   5 25-04-2021 27-04-2021  Fish
#6   6 06-04-2021 16-04-2021   Cat
#7   7 22-04-2021       <NA> Horse
#8   8 11-04-2021 21-04-2021  Fish
#9   9 25-04-2021 29-04-2021   Dog
#10 10 27-04-2021 30-04-2021   Dog
```

and in base R :

```
df3 <- rbind(df1, df2)
df3 <- df3[with(df3, order(ID, is.na(EndDate))), ]
df3 <- df3[!duplicated(df3$ID), ]
```